# Redraw or Reset table view header and/or footer

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way other than `[tableView reloadData]` to refresh table header and/or footer? With respect to both:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
OR
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

For example, I'm showing a small summary in the footer. When the data in the row changes, the affect should be reflected in the footer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UILabel and set it as section header/footer. Update the UILabel whenever you want.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return sectionFooterView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
        // create sectionFooterView in Interface Builder, change the frame here
        // use Font-size:15 , BG-Color: clearColor , text-Color: RGB=(97,105,118) 
        // and Text-alignment:Center to look like table view's original footer
    sectionFooterView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 12);
}

- (void)changeFooter {
        sectionFooterView.text = @"Footer";
}
```